# Right way of handling mouse input

Tags: unity-game-engine

I was playing around with navmesh agent and im pretty happy about the results i get. But i am a liitle bit concerned about the code getting complicated.

I want to organize my code in a way that allows me to edit it later without trying to figure it out what i did there.

what i need is basically is this:

- Handle mouse click on ground, enemies, objects, skill / spell targeting, gui
- Handle mouse over objects, enemies, gui

my approach was:

1. in update function raycast mouse position
2. check if the mouse was clicked
3. if clicked check the target tag : enemy, ground, object (loot) and
   call a related function
4. if not clicked check the target tag again for hover effects.

so what would be the best way to handle all of these listed above? any code examples in any language would be appreciated.

thanks for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its been a while that i asked this question. i ended up using state design pattern explained [here](http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/state.html).